# Does hybridization change atomic size?

Tags: hybridization

I have come to know that nitrogen can undergo both $\mathrm{sp}^3$ and $\mathrm{sp}^2$ hybridization.
Does a different hybridization lead to a different atomic radius?

Comment: Consider that a molecule has its own structure. The length of the bonds to bound test atoms does change. You might keep a full space representation but the sphere(oid)s would compenetrate each other and do so differently.

Comment: Also related are this Q and the comments it has received https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/139583/reason-for-needing-multiple-radii-for-the-same-atom

Comment: Let's be more general. Take any atomic size with a grain of salt.

Comment: How will you define a radius when sp$^3$ for example has four lobes ?

Comment: To put it bluntly: Hybridization is a stupid concept and we should finally let it die already, because otherwise we end with more generations of chemists who mistakenly think it's an actual physical thing that happens to an atom.